# Check if rewriter has any changes

Tags: java, antlr4

```
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(new JavaLexer(CharStreams.fromPath(path)));

JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
TokenStreamRewriter rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(tokens);
var myVisitor= new MyVisitor(rewriter);

myVisitor.visit(parser.compilationUnit());
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(path.toFile())) {
    out.print(rewriter.getText());
}
```

`MyVisitor` uses `TokenStreamRewriter` to change the input file. But sometimes there is nothing to change. If MyVisitor didn't change the file, then I don't have to call getText() and don't have to write the text back. (because my file is large)

Can I tell from the rewriter if there are any changes to the file?

I was trying to check `rewriter.getLastRewriteTokenIndex`, but it's always -1.

Comment: I'm looking into this, but at first glance, it appears to be a bug that the map used to retrieve the last rewrite token index is never being updated.  It may be that the name  wouldn't be quite right, as it's more likely that it was intended to track in instructionIndex, rather than the tokenIndex.  I've posted a question to the ANTLR discussion groups to see if someone has an explanation.

Comment: FYI, you can view the source at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.java  You'll notice that `getLastRewriteTokenIndex` references `lastRewriteTokenIndexes`, and while it it initialized and a method (`setLastRewriteTokenIndex`) is defined, it is never called.  (also, the method to get the lastRewriteTokenIndex for a particular "program" is marked private)

Comment: Thank you @MikeCargal. I also feel getLastRewriteTokenIndex is buggy by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this a bit, I believe that this should give you what you want:

```
package org.antlr.v4.runtime;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStreamRewriter;

public class MyTokenStreamRewriter extends TokenStreamRewriter {
    public MyTokenStreamRewriter(TokenStream tokens) {
        super(tokens);
    }

    public int getRewriteCount() {
        return getRewriteCount(DEFAULT_PROGRAM_NAME);
    }

    public int getRewriteCount(String programName) {
        return programs.get(programName).size();
    }
}
```

Then, instead of `TokenStreamRewriter`, create a `MyTokenStreamRewriter` (or whatever you wish to call it).  You really want to know how many rewrites are scheduled for a given program or the default program (not really a tokenIndex).